# UWP: NavigationView.MenuItems results empty if populated programmatically

Tags: data-binding, uwp, windows-10, uwp-xaml, winui

I created a new UWP project with a `NavigationView` (winui 2.4) in MainPage.xaml.

I proceeded by binding a hierarchical `ObservableCollection` to populate the `NavigationView` menu items (1 parent, 4 children)

Launching the application, the hierarchical structure renders as expected, and seem to be working fine.

[image: NavigationView hierarchy renders correctly]

My next objective would be to **collapse every expanded menu item clicking on a button**. To do so, the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.navigationview.collapse?view=winui-2.4) suggest using `NavigationView.Collapse(NavigationViewItem)`: my intention would be to iterate through `NavigationView.MenuItems` and collapse them.

**The issue is that it seems `NavigationView.MenuItems` returns empty** and I cannot figure out why.
I included a Button that prints `NavigationView.MenuItems.Count()`, which returns 0.

On the other hand, hard-coding the hierarchical menu items and repeating said procedure seem to work fine.

MainPage.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <muxc:NavigationView x:Name="MainNavigation" MenuItemsSource="{x:Bind categories, Mode=OneWay}">
        <muxc:NavigationView.MenuItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Category" >
                <muxc:NavigationViewItem Content="{x:Bind Name}" MenuItemsSource="{x:Bind Children}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </muxc:NavigationView.MenuItemTemplate>
        <Button Content="Do Something" Click="Button_Click" />
    </muxc:NavigationView>
</Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        ObservableCollection<Category> categories = new ObservableCollection<Category>();
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            categories = PopulateHierarchy();
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Category> PopulateHierarchy()
        {
            ObservableCollection<Category> list = new ObservableCollection<Category>();
            ObservableCollection<Category> children = new ObservableCollection<Category>();

            children.Add(new Category { Name = "Child 1" });
            children.Add(new Category { Name = "Child 2" });
            children.Add(new Category { Name = "Child 3" });
            children.Add(new Category { Name = "Child 4" });

            list.Add(new Category { Name = "Test1", Children=children });


            return list;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int itemsCount = MainNavigation.MenuItems.Count();
            Debug.WriteLine(itemsCount);
        }
    }
```

Category.cs

```
public class Category
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Category> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Edit: it seems like this is a known bug, I found a closed issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/2852#) but the problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> UWP: NavigationView.MenuItems results empty if populated programmatically

I can reproduce your problem that MenuItems.Count is zero. As your provide link said, you could also get the items with `MenuItemsSource` property.

The parameter of `Collapse` method is `NavigationViewItem`, and we could not pass MenuItems element (data source type) into it directly. We need use the data source to find the matched `NavigationViewItem`, the `ContainerFromMenuItem` method is right choice for getting  NavigationViewItem with data source. And  then `MenuItems` is not necessary for this scenario. Because `categories` has been decaled previously. we could use it directly. So the code could be written like below.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{    
    var container = MainNavigation.ContainerFromMenuItem(categories.First()) as Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationViewItem;
    MainNavigation.Collapse(container);    
}
```