# Why does NavigationView.ContainerFromMenuItem() return null except when executed from an event handler?

Tags: expand, navigationview, winui-3

I am developing a WinUI3 app containing a NavigationView. The NV uses an observable collection to populate the NavigationViewItems.

The app must support expanding and collapsing NavigationViewItems programmatically. The only way I know of to do that is to set NavigationViewItem.IsExpanded = true. And the only way I know of to get the NavigationViewItem is through NavigationView.ContainerFromMenuItem().

The trouble is, ContainerFromMenuItem always returns null except when it is executed from a button event handler (such as a Click handler). The app must perform expand/collapse without user input.

For example, I have a button that launches a Click event with this code, which works just fine to toggle an NVItem:

```cs
Category selectedItem = (Category)navview.SelectedItem;
int idx1 = Categories.IndexOf(selectedItem);
var container = (NavigationViewItem)NavView.ContainerFromMenuItem(Categories[idx1]);
if (container != null)
{
    container.IsExpanded = !container.IsExpanded;
}
```

However, that same code, when executed during app startup, such as in the MainWindow constructor after some test items are created, or in Attach(), always results in container being null.

So what am I doing wrong?

This question is somewhat similar to [UWP: NavigationView.MenuItems results empty if populated programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64806837/uwp-navigationview-menuitems-results-empty-if-populated-programmatically) but the answer to that one only deals with in-event use of ContainerFromMenuItem().

Thanks very much for any assistance on this.

Comment: Since you populate the ``NavigationViewItem``s programmatically, it should be easier to bind to ``IsExpanded`` from those objects.

Comment: Avoid code that manipulates the UI tree. Bind the UI tree to a model of yours, make sure that model implements INotifyPropertyChanged (and friends) on properties and update your model. UI will follow. 3 rules of XAML: binding, binding, binding.

Comment: Hello - I appreciate the replies.  I do follow the INotifyPropertyChanged model in my observers.  I actually did try and bind my NavigationViewItem IsExpanded property (in  my NavigationViewItem template) to a property set in code.  Whereas binding works fine for most cases, it was having no effect on the UI when I set that value in code. So either I implemented that wrong else there was some bug not allowing IsExpanded to take effect.

Comment: Have you fixed your problem? If not, it'd be easier to help you if you can share a reproducible project with minimal code on GitHub.